# Why `sed` does not return exit status if regex does not matched ?

Tags: sed

I'm trying to search and replace some line from files, but when I run `sed` if that regex not match then `sed` does not return any status code, So instead of adding one more condition with `grep`, is there way in `sed` and Why `sed` does not return exit status ?

Problem :

[image]

Comment: That one got answered on StackOverflow, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965073/return-code-of-sed-for-no-match

Comment: @DravSloan - it's OK to replicate some of the answers here, go for it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`sed` *does* return an exit status:

```
$ echo "foo" | sed 's/xx/yy/'
foo
$ echo $?
0
$ sed 's/xx/yy/' foo.txt
sed: can't read foo.txt: No such file or directory
$ echo $?
2
```

Sed's exit codes are about whether the program exited successfully or not, they have nothing to do with the internals of what `sed` is doing, just with whether or not the command managed to run.

That said, GNU sed does offer a way to do this:

```
   q [exit-code]
          Immediately  quit  the sed script without pro‐
          cessing any more input, except that  if  auto-
          print  is  not  disabled  the  current pattern
          space will be printed.  The exit code argument
          is a GNU extension.
```

For example (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15965681/1081936)):

```
$  echo "foo"|sed '/foo/ s/f/b/;q'                                                                       
boo
$  echo $?
0
$ echo "trash"|sed  '/foo/{s/f/b/;q}; /foo/!{q100}'
trash
$  echo $?
100
```

If you wanted to report the fact that *any* substitution has been successful on any line of the input, you could flag successful substitutions in the hold space and check it on the last line:

```
seq 6 | sed 's/4/four/;s/5/five/; tm;${x;/1/{x;q};x;q1};b;:m;x;s/.*/1/;x'
```

`tm` branches to the `m` label if any substitution was successful. There, we put `1` in the hold space, which we look for on the last line.

Comment: Exit-code of egrep gives info about the command is doing though, so it doesn't have to be that they don't.

Comment: @JohnyTex nobody said it had to. However, `grep` is not a good analogy. Grep is a simple program that can only do one thing: search for patterns. So sure, if it doesn't find it, it can let you know. However, `sed` is something completely different and far more complex. It is basically a scripting language and you can use it to do arbitrary tasks. It can have no way of knowing whether it was "successful" since success will depend on the details of the script you are running. Therefore, like in all programming languages, it is up to the programmer to defined the exit status.

Comment: "Exit codes are about whether a program exited successfully or not..." seems to imply that they can't have any other function though... Maybe just clarify a little.

Comment: @JohnyTex I am referring to sed's exit codes, not exit codes in general. What a program's exit code does is completely dependent upon the programmer who wrote it.

Comment: I understand that. I just think the phrasing is a bit unfortunate, though I don't really care that much actually.

Answer (score 6):

First, all commands, including `sed`, return an exit status.  You are looking for why I wouldn't be returning a failure.  Which leads to the second point.

Programs like `sed` are editors, not predicates.  They are there to change data flowing through the program.  Error conditions are for conditions like invalid internal commands or a non-existent file on the command-line.

I'm not sure of what logic you want - you don't include any expected output - but this might be what you are looking for:

```
$ sed '/^test line 7/s//#test line 7/;/^#test line 7/s//& \nAppend New Line/' test.txt
test line 1
test line 2
test line 3
test line 4
test line 5
test line 6
#test line 7
Append New Line
```

There are other constructs which can handle this as well, for example the `b` (branch) command in `sed`.

If you want an actual return code if not found, then you might want to look at `gawk` and its `exit` statement.

Comment: still it's keep appending line if we run again and again..

Comment: I have solved using grep, but want to know in sed .. https://github.com/rahulinux/bash-functions-/blob/master/CommentAppend.sh

Comment: You want to run the second statement only if the first one succeeds?  You can add the GNU extension command, `T`, between the two: `sed -i '/^test line 7/s//#&/;T;/#test line 7/&\nAppend New Line/' test.txt`